# Setting function at specific address

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm

I have the next single C code and I'm trying to compile for arm using arm-gcc GNU and eclipse.

main.h

```
#ifndef
#define MAIN_H_
extern int rmain(int,int);
#endif
```

main.c

```
#include main.h
#include sum.h
int rmain(a1,a2){
    int z=0x89;
    return sum(a1+a2)+z;
```

sum.h

```
#ifndef
#define SUM_H_
extern int sum(int,int);
#endif
```

sum.c

```
#include sum.h
int sum(int a1,int a2)
    return a1+a2;
```

My linker script file look like on this way:
mem.lds

```
ENTRY(rmain)
SECTIONS:{
.=0x808080
.text:{*(.text)}
.data:{*(.data)}
.bss:{*(.bss)}
}
```

This work OK, but my problem is that I need that function rmain will be set at 0x808080 address, so How i can do it this ?

I tryed with:

```
SECTIONS:{
.=0x808080
.start:{main.o (.text)}
.text:{*(EXCLUDE_FILE(main.o).text)}
.data:{*(.data)}
.bss:{*(.bss)}
}
```

But not luck linker say: multiple definition of rmain.

Comment: What is the command line that does the linking?  Are you listing main.o twice? And what is exact error message. (Also there are a number of missing ; { } characters in your .c and .h files.)